# Google OAuth token request returns "invalid_client": "Unauthorized"

Tags: python, oauth, google-api, google-oauth, rauth

Trying to get OAuth2 Google login working, this is the raw request that my app makes:

Method: `POST`

URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token`

Headers: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Values:

`client_id`: `XXX-0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef.apps.googleusercontent.com`

`client_secret`: `A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j0K1l2M`

`code`: `1/A1b2C3d4E5f6G7h8I9j0K1l2M3n4O5p6Q7r8S9t0U1v`

`grant_type`: `authorization_code`

`redirect_uri`: `http://localhost:5000/callback/google/`

And this is the response:

Status: `401 Unauthorized`

Body:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Have verified that this is the exact request / response that my app is making (a Python app using Flask and rauth), and have verified that I can reproduce the exact same request / response using Postman.

Per instructions in other threads, I have done all of the following in the Google APIs console:

- In "OAuth consent screen" settings, set "Product name" to something different than "Project name"
- Also in "OAuth consent screen" settings, double-check that email is set
- Enable the Google+ API
- Enable the Gmail API
- Recreate the client ID / secret
- Double-check that there are no leading or trailing spaces in the client ID / secret values, I have copied them correctly from the API console

No matter what I do, still getting the same response of `"invalid_client": "Unauthorized"`.

Help with this would be appreciated. Am trying to set up OAuth2-powered "Log in with X" functionality in my app, have gotten Facebook and Twitter working without issues, would like to get Google working too, but if I can't resolve this then I'm afraid I'll have to ditch Google auth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Invalid client** means that the client id or the client secret that you are using are not valid.  They must be the ones you have downloaded from Google Developer console.

Tip:  You might want to consider using the [Google python client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) library it does all the heavy lifting for you.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had double-checked it thoroughly, but no... I had defined the client secret in an env variable correctly, but I was then passing in the wrong env variable when actually making the token request in my app. Also, the Google python client library uses `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` (instead of `v3`), so I've changed my app to do the same, seems to work fine.

Comment: And the Google python client library also passes in the `scope` parameter when making the token request, so I've made my app do likewise, and pass in `scope`: `email`.

Comment: I had mistakenly added a space to my secret string, which was causing the issue

Comment: Spent a day after it, went this close to being full-scale mental. Finally printed out the query string and found out I forgot to pass the client_secret variable, so it was being evaluated to undefined ;-; I feel so dumb.

Comment: Would the negative voter on a two year old question care to comment i am happy to add additional information this is still valid.

Comment: I refreshed my client secret file and still got the invalid_client/unauthorized error. I had to delete token.pickle. Once token.pickle was recreated with the new client secret the error disappeared.

Comment: Yes you need to remove the token.pickle when ever you make any changes to the authorization this will cause the app to request access again.

Comment: @NayeemulIslamSwad i read your comment & checked whether I was doing the same, & yep I forgot to pass the secret id as well.

Comment: @sameerfair me too, four years later, in a next-auth app! The world keep turning, but programmers are still programmers :D

Comment: I have followed this and saved the token.pickle file. How to proceed with the next steps of making an API call and getting the google-ads data? Sorry, this is my first time with the Google-Ads API

Answer (score 1):

Refresh Cliente Secret File on https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials and delete token pickle folder