# Google API OAuth 2 and Django

Tags: python, django, google-api, google-oauth

I work on a project with Django, Google API Calendar and OAuth 2 and I have the follow error:

```
(insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.
```

When I set the `redirect_uri` with `google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow`, the **URI** that I set is: `http://localhost:8000/google/oauthcallback`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error states to use a HTTPS connection which you can either set one with an SSL certificate or allow a HTTP connection in the environment like so:

```py
import os 
os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
```

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27785830/11603043)

Comment: I set these lines but I have the follow error: (invalid_client) Unauthorized

Comment: @Alexandro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48053764/google-oauth-token-request-returns-invalid-client-unauthorized